# turtle backgroun

Tags: turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi..
As per the command: rosparam set background_r 150
The background of the turtle is expected to become red!!

But it becomes some what light blue!! i.e. its NOT RED
Is it error or can anyone plz. explain what is the issue?

Thank you.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12271/turtle-backgroun/) by [dbs12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1469/dbs12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you maybe need to set background_g and background_b to 0 first?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0